# Is Android 13 recovery build type hardcoded?

Tags: recovery-mode, android-13

My device is Tecno Spark 10 Pro and has recovery as boot ramdisk. I changed every user's fingerprint and build type from `user` to `eng` in `prop.default`, but when I boot into recovery, my build type is still `user`.

I have tried adding the `buildtype=eng` in the boot cmd line, but still get `user` when booting to recovery.

How can I change the build type in recovery?